# UNIX : Substitute value of variable inside script

Tags: unix, key, substitution

I may not have got the title perfect for this question, but I am wondering if there is a way to do the following :

Basically, I have a text file with some key value pairs and also a statement (in the same text file) which will be extracted by a shell script and which needs to also simultaneously substitute the A, B, C in the STATEMENT variable .

To make things simple, let me provide an example.

Here is my text file :

File : values.txt

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
STATEMENT=apple A orange B grape C
```

Also, I have a shell script which extracts these values and the statement from the text file and uses the STATEMENT variable as a parameter to another script it calls, something like:

Script : first_script.sh

```
A=`cat values.txt | grep -w '^A' | cut -d'=' -f2`
B=`cat values.txt | grep -w '^B' | cut -d'=' -f2`
C=`cat values.txt | grep -w '^C' | cut -d'=' -f2`
STATEMENT=`cat values.txt | grep -w 'STATEMENT' | cut -d'=' -f2`

second_script.sh $STATEMENT
```

As you can see, second_script is called from within first_script and it uses the STATEMENT variable, so what I **expect to see** with the second_script call is :

```
second_script.sh apple 1 orange 2 grape 3
```

Note that "A", "B" and "C" should get substituted to their values 1, 2 and 3.

However, what I get is still :

```
second_script.sh apple A orange B grape C
```

which is what I don't want.

How do I make sure that A, B and C get substituted to 1,2 and 3 respectively when second_script is called from first_script ?

Sorry to make it confusing.

Comment: You made it quite clear :)  I have a question, though:  Are the names A, B, and C arbitrary or fixed?  I. e. in another example, could they be V, W, X, Y, and Z or are they always A, B, and C?

Comment: Great that you could find it clear enough ! :)   They are fixed, would always be A,B and C

Comment: You can also source the file values.txt, so that you can directly use the vars set in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute values in a string like this:

```
STATEMENT=${STATEMENT/A/$A} # replace the letter A with the value of $A
STATEMENT=${STATEMENT/B/$B}
STATEMENT=${STATEMENT/C/$C}
second_script.sh "$STATEMENT"
```

If you want to match word boundaries use `sed`:

```
STATEMENT=$(sed -e "s/\bA\b/$A/g" -e "s/\bB\b/$B/g" -e "s/\bC\b/$C/g" <<< "$STATEMENT")
```

Also, you don't need to use `cat` in your script. You can do it like this:

```
A=`grep -w '^A' values.txt | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

Or, using `awk`:

```
A=$(awk -F= '/^A\y/{print $2}' values.txt)
```

**Alternatively:**

Are you able to change the `values.txt` file?

It would be easier if you could change it to:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
STATEMENT="apple $A orange $B grape $C"
```

Then in your script you could simply import the file like this:

```
. values.txt
second_script.sh "$STATEMENT"
```

Comment: You need to check that no A, B, C are in the STATEMENT elsewhere.  Consider `Apple` instead of `apple`.

Comment: @user1691717 Happy to help. Please accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -1 values.txt | {
  IFS='=' read name statement
  ./second_script.sh $(echo "$statement" | sed -r $(
    head --lines=-1 values.txt | while IFS='=' read name value
    do
      printf "%s s/\<%q\>/%q/g " "-e" "$name" "$value"
    done))
}
```

I don't like hard coded solutions, so this will read the `values.txt` file and evaluate all variables (all but last line) in the statement (last line) and give this to the `second_script.sh`.

I'd be careful about names and values containing special characters like spaces etc.  Run thorough test if you plan on using these!